# Sharing Profile Provider

Tags: asp.net

I'm building an ASP.NET solution and it's going to have 2 separate websites - 1 for users, 1 for administrators.

Both sites have a custom profile provider and I was wondering if I could, instead of referring to some classes, put the security into a webservice and then reference a class in the webservice to make it common.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Web Service to Authenticate users.

I would favor using a Business Logic Layer rather than a web service, which you would be creating a de facto business layer if you choose a web service.  That can be shared over web site.  A good design is to make you UI layer, in this case a web site, only handle UI related items.  All business logic goes into a separate class library.

You know you have done a good job creating a business layer, when you can change the UI from a web site to a windows program and have the same functions calls to create users, delete, authenticate, etc. . . .